# How do I go about hanging a hammock?

Tags: walls

I would like to replace my bed with a hammock. Without buying a stand I would like to know how to suspend it in the air. How exactly do I affix the ends of the hammock to the wall so it won't fall off, or damage the wall.

I would primarily use the hammock for sleeping, but I would like to have friends sleep over as well. How would this change the affixing method?

Answer (score 6):

This depends on your walls. Assuming your walls are the typical 2x4 studded drywall, fastening into studs is probably a bad idea; studs aren't designed to withstand that sort of horizontal load, and you'd likely damage the wall and structure over time.

An alternative might be to fasten hooks for your hammock from the wall's top plate. You'd need access above the wall in order to do this, but you could install the fastener pointing down, so that you are essentially adding to the load above the wall. Your wall is probably designed to support a load in that way, so adding a few hundred pounds shouldn't be a problem.

That does seem like quite a lot of work, though. Unless you're really sure you want this hammock to be a permanent feature of your room, it's probably less work (and definitely more flexible) to make or buy a stand. Search for "how to make a hammock stand"; there seem to be several good guides.

Comment: Agreed -- making a stand that's intended to take lateral load is a much better idea than tying into the wall.

Answer (score 3):

I've done this. I just screwed large hooks into the wall studs (I had two exterior walls opposite each other, I think they were 2x6 studs).

I used this model of hammock, from [this store](http://maisonduhamac.com/index.php/produits/hamacs/maya-double.html).
[image]
I would *strongly* recommend this type of "diagonal-sleeping" design over the type with spreader bars (which can dump you out of the hammock very easily). i would suggest getting the two-person size even if you only planned to sleep alone, as it gives a lot more chances to find a comfortable position.

I did it because my room too hot for sleeping in summer, and the hammock solved this issue very well (maybe too well, see below). Being able to hook it out of the way and not using a frame mean that there was a lot more useful area in my room. Some comments, though:

- your end points have to be *exactly* the right distance apart. Extending with a short piece of rope, or shortening by tying a knot in the end of the hammock will adjust the length, but the hammock does not hang as well with either method;
- Pay close attention to the height that you hang it: I put mine about an inch too high and it made it just a little precarious to get in and out (and worse for shorter guests);
- there is room for two people in it, but I would say it's only for occasional use, and some guests might be nervous about it. You will definitely wake each other if you try to leave the hammock;
- you need be sure the temperature of the room never gets too low, because a blanket does not really help when you are exposed on all sides, and you can't wear heavy clothes because the hammock may catch and break a thread (you can retie it, but still). Even in the middle of summer where my room was unbearably hot at 1am, by 5am it often cooled enough that I would have to leave the hammock. If you have replaced your other bed with the hammock, then about your only options are a warm hat or waking early if this happens.